# Can I remove request calls in the Newman CLI Reporting?

Tags: testing, postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, postman-newman

I am in the process of converting an application's testing API Framework from Karate to Postman / Newman. I have all of the tests passing and everything is going well. However, due to the size of the application there are a lot of tests and requests being hit (including pre-requests). I'm trying to shorten the cli reporting to just show the name of the request and the assertions whether they pass or not. I'm trying to remove displaying the calls being made in the request themselves, is there a way to do this?

I've found similar options such as `--reporter-cli-no-success-assertions`, `--reporter-cli-no-summary`, and so on and so forth.

Current command I am using (with some modifications), `newman run postman_collection.json -e environment.json --folder "api" --reporters cli,htmlextra --env-var "env=mocked" --reporter-htmlextra-export result.html --reporter-htmlextra-skipHeaders "Authorization" --reporter-htmlextra-title "App Report" --reporter-htmlextra-browserTitle "App Report" --insecure`.

Thank you in advance!